# PHP: file_put_contents and writing to multiple files in a for loop not working

Tags: php, fopen, file-put-contents

For some background I have a bit of code that I am using to generate html files that contain a link to a unique code. Ultimately this ends up on a USB drive thats distributed to customers. This is done in batch so i can create as many custom files with code as needed.

```
if ( !empty($_POST) ) {

$url = trim($_POST['url']);

$codes = trim($_POST['codes']);

$codes_array = explode("\n", $codes);

$codes_array = array_filter($codes_array, 'trim');

foreach ($codes_array as $code) {

    $html = <<<EOD
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="$url$code">Download Now</a>
</body>
</html>
EOD;

    file_put_contents("codes/".$code.".html",$html);

}

}
```

What happens is only one file is generated in that folder, but its name is always the last element in the array, the other files don't get generated, it seems like the files getting overwritten even though $code is different on each iteration.

I tried the following code as well with same results.

```
$fh = fopen("codes/".$code.".html", "w+");
fwrite($fh, $html);
fclose($fh);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `echo`ing `$code` on each loop to check the value. Or `print_r($codes_array)` before the loop to make sure its what you think. And I think you want `array_map` in place of `array_filter`

Comment: Yeah already tried echoing the $code variable on loop and values are showing as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$codes_array = array_filter($codes_array, 'trim');
```

with

```
$codes_array = array_map('trim', $codes_array);
```

Otherwise, only the last element will not have `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try:

```
foreach ($codes_array as $key => $value ) {

    $html = <<<EOD
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="$url$code">Download Now</a>
</body>
</html>
EOD;

    file_put_contents("codes/".$value.".html",$html);

}
```

Is it the same result?